# Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. inside Docker container

Tags: docker, npm, npm-install, node-sass, sass-loader

I get this error while trying to build Docker container from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
frontend:
    build:
      context: ./my-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./my-app:/app
      # - ./my-app/node_modules:/app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
```

and here's Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm ci
EXPOSE 8082
```

The reason I ask despite some other people already asked similar question is that this one is inside container. It's really weird having to rebuild freshly installed node modules every time.

Versions of loaders:

```
"node-sass": "^4.12.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
```

Comment: Does this help?  https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1028

Comment: Apparently alpine and node-sass don't play nice. How about this https://github.com/blairg/docker-node-sass-alpine ?

Comment: Not really. I tried `node:10.17-alpine` but didn't helped. Also, I'm using `node-sass` 4.12.0 so it should already support node lts. Thanks tho

Comment: @tony Interesting, but there must be som clean solution. Too many people are using `node-sass`

Comment: I agree there must be something clean or a small discrepancy. Do you get a different output if you uncomment node_modules mounting?

Comment: Output is exactly the same unfortunately

Comment: Okay, I think it might actually do something with environment bindings. I build on MacOS and then try to build same thing on Alpine...or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes, bind-mounting your host's `node_modules` tree into a container won't work if they're different operating systems.  Delete the `volumes:` line to use what's built into the image.  (You're also missing the `COPY` line in your `Dockerfile` to copy the actual application in.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I actually put `node_modules` into `.dockerignore` so the container can install them on their own, but somehow it doesn't work. Also, I want to keep hot module reload (it's a Vue.js app)